# Block website access using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, desktop-application, windows

Today i need some help in which i want to create desktop application in C# which can block the website access for specified time interval. I already done R&D on that and find that we can achieve it using following sample code.

```
String path = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
String sitetoblock = "\n 127.0.0.1 stackoverflow.com";
sw.Write(sitetoblock);
sw.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Site Blocked");
```

As you can see in above code that we can achieve it using hosts file in windows directory but i don't want to done it through this way. so is there any another way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance !!!!

Comment: Is this for an individual PC or a domain? This is a bit of a shopping question: *I can do it this way - what other ways are there?*

Comment: @JeremyThompson  what would be other way to ask ? Any given problem can be solved in number of ways .

Comment: @loneshark99 I would state why the method isn't satisfactory, eg *modifying the host file can be undone by users and changing client configuration is undesirable, is there a way to block websites beyond the users control?*. At least Nikhil did do some research, for that reason I didn't vote close as a shopping question and only mentioned it as a passing comment.

Comment: @JeremyThompson got it, I would think if he knew what host file is, he wouldn't post that as one of the alternatives . Anyways , I am getting back to my normal mood from my cranky mood :). Also I am not in a position to judge what someone knows and doesn't know .

Comment: yes this is for individual PC but if user manually changes hosts file then it also getting affected so i need some another alternative to achieve this. if you look at the https://getcoldturkey.com/ then this application blocking site without hosts file and may be creating some task schedulers.

Comment: you could write this as a service... which updates the host file every say 2-5 seconds... this way even if they change it. it will be changed back... this will be come so annoying they they will no longer bother changing it. you could also write a service to monitor the file for modifications... if they detected change the file back.

Comment: @Seabizkit if user has rights to modify `etc\hosts` on Windows, it also has the rights to stop your service or application.

Comment: @RemusRusanu what? please explain more don't understand your point you are trying to make. please member i did not make the question or come up with the scenario. PS he wanted to make a "Block website access using C#" stop the service or application, yeah sure, what alternative were you suggesting? which uses c# to block websites. PS i would suggest a proxy server but that's not really c# application so i'm at a loss...

Comment: Modifying `etc\hosts` is a priviledged operation, it requires `BUILTIN\Administrators` or `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. You are proposing a arms race against local administrator. That it will always be lost by the application, an administrator can simply stop it, kill it etc. So there is no point recommending 'writing every 5 seconds'. Either the user can modify etc\hosts, in which case he is an administrator and can control the applications and services running, or is not in which case writing once is enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Windows Filtering Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510(v=vs.85).aspx), which is purpose build for this. <strike>Here is an old and dated article about how to do this from C#: [Packet Filtering in .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4585/Packet-Filtering-in-NET)</strike> (the article is using the previous, deprecated, Win2K [Packet Filtering API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/porting-packet-processing-drivers-and-apps-to-wfp)). Here is a [thread discussing WFP in C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a65bf197-937b-401e-b15f-0e1c3decdb14/windows-filtering-platform-and-net?forum=wfp).

Note though that this sort of blocking is best done at the router, outside of any possible user interference.